# OpenCV 2.4.7 build on MacOS (Maverick + Xcode 5.01 + CUDA 5.5)

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv, cuda, osx-mavericks

I couldn't build opencv with cuda support on Mavericks:
When using cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DWITH_CUDA=ON ..

i got error:
 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Any workaround on this?
(Similar error when using macport too)

CMakeError.log

```
Determining size of off64_t failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/opt/local/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec3929617441/fast"
/opt/local/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3929617441.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3929617441.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3929617441.dir/OFF64_T.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -fsigned-char -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3929617441.dir/OFF64_T.c.o   -c /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c:19:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'off64_t'; did you mean 'off_t'?
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 10000)%10)),
           ^
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c:17:22: note: expanded from macro 'SIZE'
#define SIZE (sizeof(off64_t))
                     ^
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c:20:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'off64_t'; did you mean 'off_t'?
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 1000)%10)),
           ^
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c:17:22: note: expanded from macro 'SIZE'
#define SIZE (sizeof(off64_t))
                     ^
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c:21:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'off64_t'; did you mean 'off_t'?
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 100)%10)),
           ^
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c:17:22: note: expanded from macro 'SIZE'
#define SIZE (sizeof(off64_t))
                     ^
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c:22:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'off64_t'; did you mean 'off_t'?
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 10)%10)),
           ^
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c:17:22: note: expanded from macro 'SIZE'
#define SIZE (sizeof(off64_t))
                     ^
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c:23:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'off64_t'; did you mean 'off_t'?
  ('0' +  (SIZE    % 10)),
           ^
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c:17:22: note: expanded from macro 'SIZE'
#define SIZE (sizeof(off64_t))
                     ^
5 errors generated.
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3929617441.dir/OFF64_T.c.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec3929617441/fast] Error 2

/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c:
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>


#undef KEY
#if defined(__i386)
# define KEY '_','_','i','3','8','6'
#elif defined(__x86_64)
# define KEY '_','_','x','8','6','_','6','4'
#elif defined(__ppc__)
# define KEY '_','_','p','p','c','_','_'
#elif defined(__ppc64__)
# define KEY '_','_','p','p','c','6','4','_','_'
#endif

#define SIZE (sizeof(off64_t))
char info_size[] =  {'I', 'N', 'F', 'O', ':', 's','i','z','e','[',
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 10000)%10)),
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 1000)%10)),
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 100)%10)),
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 10)%10)),
  ('0' +  (SIZE    % 10)),
  ']',
#ifdef KEY
  ' ','k','e','y','[', KEY, ']',
#endif
  '\0'};

#ifdef __CLASSIC_C__
int main(argc, argv) int argc; char *argv[];
#else
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
#endif
{
  int require = 0;
  require += info_size[argc];
  (void)argv;
  return require;
}


Determining if the include file io.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/opt/local/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec647810530/fast"
/opt/local/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec647810530.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec647810530.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec647810530.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -fsigned-char -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec647810530.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: 'io.h' file not found
#include <io.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec647810530.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec647810530/fast] Error 2


Determining if the function jbg_newlen exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/opt/local/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec4172827471/fast"
/opt/local/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4172827471.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4172827471.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4172827471.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -fsigned-char -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=jbg_newlen -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4172827471.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /opt/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec4172827471
/opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4172827471.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc     -fsigned-char -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=jbg_newlen -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4172827471.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec4172827471  
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_jbg_newlen", referenced from:
      _main in CheckFunctionExists.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec4172827471] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec4172827471/fast] Error 2


Determining if the include file linux/videodev.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/opt/local/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec70111243/fast"
/opt/local/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec70111243.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec70111243.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec70111243.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -fsigned-char -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec70111243.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: 'linux/videodev.h' file not found
#include <linux/videodev.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec70111243.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec70111243/fast] Error 2


Determining if the include file linux/videodev2.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/opt/local/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec661389614/fast"
/opt/local/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec661389614.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec661389614.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec661389614.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -fsigned-char -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec661389614.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: 'linux/videodev2.h' file not found
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec661389614.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec661389614/fast] Error 2


Determining if the include file sys/videoio.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/opt/local/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec741892054/fast"
/opt/local/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec741892054.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec741892054.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec741892054.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -fsigned-char -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec741892054.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: 'sys/videoio.h' file not found
#include <sys/videoio.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec741892054.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec741892054/fast] Error 2


Determining if the include file libavformat/avformat.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/opt/local/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec2161613468/fast"
/opt/local/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2161613468.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2161613468.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2161613468.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -fsigned-char -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2161613468.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: 'libavformat/avformat.h' file not found
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2161613468.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec2161613468/fast] Error 2


Determining if the include file ffmpeg/avformat.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/opt/local/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec188285781/fast"
/opt/local/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec188285781.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec188285781.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec188285781.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -fsigned-char -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec188285781.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: 'ffmpeg/avformat.h' file not found
#include <ffmpeg/avformat.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec188285781.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/Users/caominhvu/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec188285781/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: Please, add the full cmake log. Otherwise, it's unclear what has actually went wrong.

Comment: I've added CMakeError.log file. I can build successfully by disable cuda support ( use cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DWITH_CUDA=OFF ..) but i need cuda for my project

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I compiled OpenCV 2.4.8 on OSX Mavericks 10.9.1 using Xcode 5.0.2 and CUDA 5.5:

- open CMake to set the project, and to the basic configuration
- in latest Xcode (I think >= 5) there's no more the gcc compiler, deprecated in favor of clang, so  go to the CUDA options of the CMAKE project and change CUDA_HOST_COMPILER to use "/usr/bin/clang". Luckily CUDA 5.5 supports clang and not only gcc
- Apparently CUDA 5.5 supports only the older libstdc++ library and not the more modern libc++, so update CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS to tell mvcc to pass tell the nativa compilar to use this older library. Add "-Xcompiler -stdlib=libstdc++; -Xlinker -stdlib=libstdc++"
- Tell also the C++ compiler that compiles the rest of the library to use libstdc++: show the advanced options of CMAKE and go to CMAKE to add "-stdlib=libstdc++" to both CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is how to compile OpenCV with CUDA support. Everything works perfectly with default configuration but enable CUDA

Comment: Cao, the instructions I've written describe how I've compiled OpenCV with CUDA support.

Comment: I checked and failed again. Could you please post the full cmake command (for using CMAKE by command line) or some screenshots (for using CMAKE by GUI) ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here later who may be trying to install from [this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/). I ran into this problem because my OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH was pointing to the wrong directory. I had mine in ~/src/, and not just ~/